# Patch DOM after ads remotion - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I've created a simple adblocker for google chrome and I'm testing it.
It seems working correctly and will block using `webRequest` all the ads that are in easylist filters.

I'm looking for a way to "patch" the DOM web pages when a blank space is left from a removed ads. Since it's impossible to predict what will be the css ids and classes of these banners, I would ask if there is a way to achive this. I've seen that on the easylist repo are available some lists of filters that will reference to DOM classes and ids but I don't know how to parse them to use inside the extension, can someone suggest me how to proceed please?

I want to use regex but the needed values will be lost after the `.replace()` js function. Here is how the list looks like:

```
###zoneAdserverSuper
###zoneAdvertisment
###zone_a_ad
###zone_b_ad
###zone_c_ads
###zztextad
##.AD-POST
##.AD-RC-300x250
##.AD-Rotate
##.AD-label300x250
##.AD300
##.AD300Block
##.AD300x250
```

to see how is structured the list [here is the link](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/blob/master/easylist/easylist_general_hide.txt)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You'll have to do it manually in the content script. Might be easier to switch to declarativeNetRequest which collapses the empty placeholders automatically (not always though).

Comment: Can you show us a code snippet of what you've tried?

Comment: I've already tested `declarativeNetRequest` and it's a bit tricky to mantain because needs to have rules defined inside static `.json` files and also with the dynamic update function provided by the api, the list processing require a lot of regex and mapping. This api isn't mature yet and lack in documentation examples for rules updating.

Comment: @Reyno I didn't have any code for this at the moment. this is why I'm asking for some tips on how to proceed.

Comment: The declarativeNetRequest API is quite mature already, it won't change significantly. Mapping shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, there's a trick for webRequest: you can redirect the resources to `'data:text/plain,'` URL instead of canceling them, so this will collapse ads without explicit width/height.

Comment: @wOxxOm so insetad of `return { cancel: true }` I can do something like `return { redirectUrl: "data:text/plain" }` ?

Comment: Yes but you've lost the comma.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse the whole list on the REPO you can do the following.

1. Get data into an array.
2. Remove every line that starts with an `!`
3. Remove first two characters from string `##`
4. Get all the DOM elements based on the selector
5. Do whatever you want with them...

PS if you don't request the list but save it inside the extension you could just do this before hand so you don't need to parse this through code everytime. Just save the parsed version inside the extension.

```js
const data = [
  '##div[class^="backfill-taboola-home-slot-"]',
  '! Tripadvisor',
  '###MAIN.ShowTopic > .ad',
  '! uCoz',
  '! https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=13414',
  '##div[id^="mainads"]',
  '! yavli.com Sponsored content',
  '##.__y_elastic .__y_item',
  '##.__y_inner > .__y_item',
  '##.__y_outer',
  '##.__yinit .__y_item',
  '##.__ywl .__y_item',
  '##.__ywvr .__y_item',
  '##.__zinit .__y_item',
  '##.icons-rss-feed + .icons-rss-feed div[class$="_item"]',
  '##.inlineNewsletterSubscription + .inlineNewsletterSubscription div[class$="_item"]',
  '##.jobs-information-call-to-action + .jobs-information-call-to-action div[class$="_item"]',
  '! Zergnet',
  '###boxes-box-zergnet_module',
  '###right_rail-zergnet',
  '###zergnet',
  '###zergnet-wrapper',
  '##.ZERGNET',
];

const combined = data.filter((selector) => !selector.startsWith("!")).map((selector) => {
  const domSelector = selector.slice(2, selector.length);
  return domSelector ? [...document.querySelectorAll(domSelector)] : [];
}).flat();

console.log(combined);
```

```html
<div class="backfill-taboola-home-slot-five">FAKE AD</div>

<div class="header">NOT AN AD</div>

<div class="__y_elastic">
  <div class="__y_item">FAKE AD</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">NOT AN AD</div>

<div id="zergnet-wrapper">FAKE AD</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I need to give it a try. Do you have any suggestion about `declarativeNetrequest` too if I want to map filters list to dynamically update the rules?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with declarativeNetRequest (yet), so i can't really help you there. Though i know there is a [package](https://github.com/kzar/abp2chromerules) which converts AdBlock list to declarativeNetrequest list so maybe that can help you

Comment: I know that package, I've used it to create the rules I've tested  with the api but it's not very helpful because ruleset needs to be regenerated each time easylist is updated. anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: I get this error when the script is running `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty.` Are you sure that I can use `querySelectorAll` in this way?

Comment: Their seems to be some empty selectors in the list, i updated the snippet to check for them. Should be working now, my local test works.

Comment: ok, I need to test. It would be better for performances to process only the DOM elements that are available and needs to be removed instead of the whole list.